# Get Websocket session data in Spring when handing STOMP SEND

Tags: java, spring, session, websocket, spring-websocket

Spring Websocket tutorial tells that if I like to handle STOMP SEND command, I shall use (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/greeting") {
    public String handle(String greeting) {
    return "[" + getTimestamp() + ": " + greeting;
    }

}
```

I need however also know which Websocket Session was sending this, in order to do the check like

```
if (sessionIsAllowedToDoThings(sessionData))   {...}
```

How I can therefore get Websocket Session data for this example?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can obtain websocket's session id (and other fields) by adding `org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor` parameter to your `handle(String)` method: `handle(String, StompHeaderAccessor)`.

If you want to access your real `JSESSIONID` attribute, you have to create an implementation of `org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeInterceptor` like so (it is written in Kotlin):

```
class HttpHandshakeInterceptor : HandshakeInterceptor {

    companion object {
        const val ATTRIBUTE_SESSION_ID = "sessionId"
    }

    override fun beforeHandshake(request: ServerHttpRequest, response: ServerHttpResponse, wsHandler: WebSocketHandler, attributes: MutableMap<String, Any>): Boolean {
        attributes[ATTRIBUTE_SESSION_ID] = (request as ServletServerHttpRequest).servletRequest.session.id
        return true
    }

    override fun afterHandshake(request: ServerHttpRequest, response: ServerHttpResponse, wsHandler: WebSocketHandler, exception: Exception?) {}
}
```

and register it wihtin your `org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` like so:

```
override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint").addInterceptors(httpHandshakeInterceptor)
}
```

The main idea here is that you intercept the initial handshake and store real session id within the websocket attributes. The attributes are available through `StompHeaderAccessor` you passed to your `handle(String, StompHeaderAccessor)` method.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to use StompHeaderAccessor but I've added `@Headers Map<String, Object> headers` param to the method annotated with `@MessageMapping` and looks like it's working. The attributes set in the HandshakeInterceptor are stored in a nested map under the `simpSessionAttributes` key.

Comment: Good to know :) Thanks.